# Purpose of a resistor in active filter circuit

Tags: operational-amplifier, active-filter

I am currently analysing this circuit, and even though its purpose is clear to me I am unable to tell what is R17 supposed to do. Is it there just to set gain? I would be grateful for any explanation, as I don't have that much experience with hardware
[image: Circuit in question]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a second order Sallen-Key filter.

R17 is basically a piece of wire, at least compared to the input resistance of the op-amp, and sets its gain to approximately unity.

Why use a resistor instead of a bit of wire? It's the same value as R18. This means that input bias currents drawn by the amplifier tend to create the same drop in R17 and R18, giving the filter as close to zero DC output as practical, for that class of op-amp. If you really want zero DC output, then there are opamps with better voltage offsets than the LF356. With its typically 30pA input bias current, the offset voltage in 22kohms is negligible.

Were it a much much faster opamp, then you would find it modifying its frequency response, especially if there was significant stray capacitance to ground at the inverting input.

Comment: Great stuff, thank you guys for answers - the idea behind it is clear to me now. I'm just a bit confused with the claim that gain would be approximately unity. From my (sadly low) understanding wouldn't the gain be 1 + R17/R15?

Comment: R15 is driven by the (near) zero output impedance of the opamp, and drives the filter network. As such, it does influence the gain versus frequency of the whole filter stage. However, it doesn't affect the closed-loop gain of the U2. A single resistor to ground from the inverting input would form a potential divider with R17 and change the opamp gain. For instance, a 22k to ground from the inverting input would give the opamp a gain of 2. This would incidentally change the filter response if the values of the Cs and Rs stayed unaltered.

Comment: Spent some time with the circuit, read about what you wrote. I get it now, thank you for helping me to learn!

Answer (score 1):

In a typical Sallen Key high pass filter:

[image]

There is no "R17" present as it is in your schematic.

The reason to add it anyway is to make the influence of the input DC biasing currents smaller. Some opamps draw a (small) current from their inputs. This current is often needed to bias the input transistors. Usually this current is only of significant value when the opamp uses bipolar input transistors so NPN or PNP.

This input current causes a small voltage to drop across (in your circuit) R17 and R18 and in my circuit, only across R2.

In your circuit, as the voltage drop occurs for **both** opamp inputs, it is cancelled out as the opamp only amplifies the **difference** between the voltages at its inputs.

In my circuit only the + input has the resistor so only the + input will see the extra DC voltage so it does not cancel out.

*Does that make your circuit "better"?*

Regarding DC offset yes, but only when the opamp has a significant input biasing current.
The LF356 is an opamp which has JFET inputs and that means that the input current is **extremely small**, in the order of the reverse leakage current of a diode. So for the LF356 the extra resistor R17 isn't really needed as the DC voltage cross R17 will be so small that it can be neglected. But if you would replace the LF356 with an opamp which had NPN and/or PNP inputs then R17 might improve the DC offset.